# equalsIgnoreCase is called on itself. Error

Tags: java

My exercise is to create a String variable called "Hallo". I should check, if the String is called "Hallo" with a scanner. If its true, my code should answer with "Hallo". If not, the code should answer with "Tschüss".

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String hallo = "Hallo.";

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        {
            System.out.println(input);

                input.nextLine();
                

            if (hallo.equalsIgnoreCase(hallo)) {
                System.out.println(hallo);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Tschüss.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are never storing your input in a variable and then call `equalsIgnoreCase` on itself. Why?

Comment: What's the error?  Also, under what circumstances do you expect `hallo.equalsIgnoreCase(hallo)` to *ever* be `false`?

Comment: My friend said I should try it on my own, so I searched in the internet for some scanner files. Idk what I am doing xd

Answer (score 1):

`input.nextLine();` returns a String. You need to store the result into a variable like `String userResponse = input.nextLine();` then in your condition do `if(userResponse.equalsIgnoreCase(hello))`. Because in your code you test if your variable hello is equals to your variable hello. It can only be true. You need to store the response of the user and then test if it's equal to your variable hello

Comment: Hello, there is no error anymore. The problem is, that it still answers with "Tschüss". But I'm writing "Hallo". Sorry for my dumb question but how can I fix this?

Comment: Your string varaible named hallo stored "Hallo." there is a dot after Hallo

Comment: You're right. Thank you very much. Now it works. I am so f*cking dumb haha xD

Do you have discord? Would be nice if I can add you there, if I have any questions or something :)